# What is the python equivalent of grep -v?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, python

I like `grep -v`. I use it all the time. But I am also doing some text processing in python, and there is one crucial thing that I lack.

Usually, I use `grep -v` to take extraneous stuff out of text.

For instance,

```
$ grep -v '[a-z]'
# (I manually review this output to confirm that I don't want those lines)

$ grep '[a-z]' > linesiwanted
```

But how do I match the complement of a regex in Python? For instance, the complement of `\w`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164414/how-to-inverse-match-with-regex

Comment: There's a similar discussion about grep in python on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921894/grep-and-python, this question more specific version of that

Comment: \w = any word char
\W = any non-word char

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A regex in Python, either the `search` or `match` methods, returns a `Match` object or `None`.  For `grep -v` equivalent, you might use:

```python
import re
for line in sys.stdin:
    if re.search(r'[a-z]', line) is None:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Or more concisely:

```python
import re; sys.stdout.writelines([line for line in sys.stdin if re.search(r'[a-z]', line) is None])
```

Comment: +1 the SO link in the comment mentions negative-lookahead assertions but to be honest i think your snippet is much more sensible and elegant. thanks.

Comment: it turns out you can also use [^a-z] to match the complement of the set [a-z]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can just use [^a-z] to mean `grep -v [a-z]`.

I'm using it like:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

import sys, re

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    f = open(file)
    string = f.read()
    regex = re.compile('[^a-z]')
    subs = regex.sub('', string)
    f.close()
    print subs
```

Comment: **These are not the same.** `grep -v '[a-z]'` means "exclude any line containing a character in the range from `a` to `z`" but you've implemented `grep '[^a-z]'` which means "include any line containing a character _not_ in the range from `a` to `z`." If a line has `abc123` then your query will erroneously print it because `1` satisfies that criteria. `grep -v '[a-z]'` will not print this line because `a` satisfies the negated criteria.